# How to handle editing knockout ViewModel in modal dialog

Tags: knockout.js

I am building a wizard-style interface using knockout.js where the final stage allows the user to review the information they have entered. There are links which open a modal dialog where portions of their information can be edited.

How would I go about handling the update of my knockout ViewModel such that the main ViewModel object only gets updated when the dialog is 'Accepted'?  Note; if the user cancels the dialog, the original ViewModel should remain unchanged.

Comment: Do you have any code you can post? You are asking for a lot without giving us much to go on.

Comment: Do you have Underscore or jQuery on your page (their util functions would be useful here)?

Comment: @Tyrsius - I have quite a lot of javascript/html to post here. I was just aiming to get a very general approach to solving the problem.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand - I am currently using jQuery along with jQuery Simple Modal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are just looking for a general solution, then it's pretty straightforward.

```
//main Viewmodel

self.openDialog = function() {
    var copy = //copy wizard with preferred method
    self.dialogItem(copy);
    self.isShowingDialog(true); 
};

self.acceptDialog = function() {
    self.isShowingDialog(false);
    var result = //copy self.dialogItem with preferred method
    self.wizard(result);
};
```

### Update

I prefer to use Knockouts super-mega-awesome copy function: `ko.toJS(viewmodel)`. It makes a copy of the object by unwrapping all the observables so you have a plain object. If your constructor function takes an object as a parameter, you can then use this object to build a fresh copy. It might look like this

```
var Wizard = function(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = ko.observable(data.id || 0);
    self.name = ko.observable(data.name || '');
    self.otherThing = ko.observable(data.otherThing || '');
};

...

var copy = new Wizard(ko.toJS(original));
```

Now you have a solid copy.

Comment: Thanks for this. The thing I was trying to get at with my question was how best to handle the copying of the viewmodel object (apologies for not articulating this better) Is the only option, just to write a method to copy each of the object's members? This answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306130/jqueryui-modal-dialog-breaks-knockoutjs-bindings#10452522 describes another way, but it still boils down to eventually having to copy each member, which I would like to avoid if possible.